# Rendering Problem: bad resolution

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am new to blender. I am not able to render a scene correctly. I was following a tutorial on geometry nodes. Before i began I tried to render the scene but i couldnt get the color or even resolution correctly. Is it because blender ran out of memory ?

[Tutorial i am following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_8xTV3IP3A&list=PLgO2ChD7acqHzccBuhAGw8dTPLnR1E3QB&index=6)

Specs -
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9300H CPU @ 2.40GHz   2.40 GHz
Installed RAM 24 GB
Video RAM 4GB[image]

I tried GPU and CPU rendering same result.
[File](https://filebin.net/ub103kjb7rplmfpk/Mesh_Curve.blend)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

From your description it is not quite clear what the issue is - no worries it can be really tough at the beginning learning this complex software. I am just mentioning it, because this is *my best guess* to what your problem may be. If I didn't answer your question, don't hesitate to ask again with speficications :)

1. You are using a metallic material. Metal is essentially all reflections, so it needs stuff to reflect in order to look good. Currently in your scene all there is to reflect is one light and a whole bunch of grey. So the render is actually correct, no technical issue. You just need an environment. The common way to achieve this is using an *HDRI* - a spherical high-dynamic-range image that works similar to a skybox in video games.

You can define your HDRI by choosing *Environment Texture* under *Color* in the world tab:
[image: world tab settings for environment texture]
[image: open file for environment texture]

Using [this free studio HDRI from Polyhaven](https://polyhaven.com/a/studio_small_08) and not changing anything else about your scene, I got it to look like this:
[image: metallic material render with HDRI texture]

You can find many free HDRIS on [Polyhaven](https://polyhaven.com/hdris) to try out what look works best for you.

**Note:** the Material Preview viewport mode comes with built-in HDRI textures, that's why your material looks different from the render there.
[image: HDRI map selection for viewport render]

2. You may also want to right-click your model in object mode and select *Shade Smooth* to make your Suzannes look - well - smoother:
   [image: same render as above but with smooth shading enabled]

**Note:** You do have a *Set Shade Smooth* node in your Geometry Node tree, but it only affects the icospheres. The Suzanne heads inherit the shading mode from the input geometry of your base mesh object.
Alternatively to setting the base model to *Shade Smooth*, you could also put another *Set Shade Smooth* node right after the geometry output of the *Group Input* node. This would have the same effect in this case.

Hopefully I was able to answer your question. As mentioned above, if not, by all means ask again with more spefics. Happy Blendering!

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you so much. Shade Smooth node and light source were missing.